# How to avoid reading back in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I am implementing an algorithm with OpenCL. I will loop in C++ many times and call a same OpenCL kernel each time. The kernel will generate the input data of next iteration and the number of these data. Currently, I read back this number in each loop for two usages:

1. I use this number to decide how many work items I need for next loop; and
2. I use this number to decide when to exit the loop (when the number is 0).

I found the reading takes most of time of the loop. Is there any way to avoid it?

Generally speaking, if you need to call a kernel repeatedly, and the exit condition is dependent to the result generated by the kernel (not fixed number loops), how can you do it efficiently? Is there anything like the occlusion query in OpenGL that you can just do some query instead of reading back from GPU?

Answer (score 2):

Reading a number back from a GPU  Kernel will always take 10s - 1000s  microseconds or more.

If the  controlling number is always reducing, you can keep in global memory, and test  it against  the global id  and decide if the kernel does work or not on each iteration.  Use  a global memory barrier to sync all the threads ...

```
kernel void x(global int * the_number, constant int max_iterations, ... )
{
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    int count = 0;    // stops an infinite loop

     while( index  < the_number[0] && count < max_iterations )
     {
      count++;
      // loop code follows

      ....

      // Use one thread decide what to do next 
      if ( index  == 0 )
      {
          the_number[0] = ... next value
      }

      barrier( CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE ); //  Barrier to sync threads
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here:

1. If possible, you can simply move the loop and the conditional into the kernel? Use a scheme where additional work items do nothing depending on the input for the current iteration.
2. If 1. isn't possible, I would recommend that you store the data generated by the "decision" kernel in a buffer and use that buffer to "direct" your other kernels.

Both these options will allow you to skip the readback.

Comment: If I launch many work items (say 1000), and most of them (say 990) do nothing. E.g. they test a condition and return immediately if it is false. Dose it have the similar speed as just launching 10 work items? Or will it be much slower?

Comment: I don't see why that'd be a bad thing. As long as there's no readback, it should only take as long as the longest running work items in a workgroup, correct?

Comment: My real program is more complicated. I call many kernels in each loop. And I do not think it is possible to implement the work of the whole loop into a kernel. :(

Comment: I see, I will edit my answer. Your original question made it seem easy enough :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just finishing up some research where we had to tackle this exact problem!

We discovered a couple of things:

1. Use two (or more) buffers! Have the first iteration of the kernel
   operate on data in b1, then the next on b2, then on b1 again. In
   between each kernel call, read back the result of the other buffer
   and check to see if it's time to stop iterating. Works best when the kernel takes longer than a read. Use a profiling tool to make sure you aren't waiting on reads (and if you are, increase the number of buffers).
2. Over shoot! Add a finishing check to each kernel, and call it
   several (100s) of times before copying data back. If your kernel is
   low-cost, this can work very well.